# Table overriding/ disappearing

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently writing a script which uses `ajax` to call `php` for pulling in table data using a lazy load method by for some reason whenever i add to the end using

```
document.getElementById("updateTable").innerHTML += tabledata;
```

it seems to remove some of the first load of row at the beginning. has anyone else experienced this problem.
the `php` generates the `HTML` and then sends it to the `JavaScript` to be added onto the previous section of the table but i cannot for the life of me figure out why it is being removed. this is the only line of code that i use which directly effects the element `updateTable`.

Have any of you experienced this problem or does anyone have any creative ideas on solving this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look at this

Something like this,

Soccer

Tennis

```
var nodetag = document.createElement("LI");
var nodecontent = document.createTextNode("Aayo");         
nodetag.appendChild(nodecontent);                            
document.getElementById("currrentList").appendChild(nodecontent);
```